# Vue.js updated() only when a specific array changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am currently working on a chat and want a function that scrolls down to end of the div after data is added to an array.

`updated()` pretty much works fine but we also have a `vue-timepicker` in the component which displays a timer so the `$nextTick()` gets executed every second and you cannot scroll up.

Any ideas how to execute the `$nextTick()` only when the array with messages changes or any other thoughts?

```
updated() {
        this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToBottom());
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to watch the exact property that changes

```js
watch: {
  value(val) {
    // executes when value changes
    this.$nextTick(() => this.scrollToBottom());
  },
},
```

Here you can read more about it https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch.

Note that `updated` is discouraged for this use case:

> To react to state changes, it’s usually better to use a computed property or watcher instead.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Answer (score 1):

You could [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) that array like :

```
watch:{
    arrName:{
      handler(newVal,oldVal){
          this.scrollToBottom()
      },
     deep:true

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem with this solution is that it only scrolls down to the penultimate message and not the last.

Comment: please provide more details in your question and add a code to debug